# Meteor: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: node.js, meteor, websocket

What could be the possible cause of the error `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`?

The app is hosted on ubuntu and deployed using the npm `mup` package. I included my bundled ssl pem file within mup.json.

Is there anything else that I need to configure on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by one of the three reasons:

1. Some ISPs may use proxies which don't support websockets. This is more apparent over 3G networks
2. If your app has crashed. Meteor tries to connect to the server and can't since it's not online.
3. This can also happen if Nginx isn't configured to use WebSockets, and your MUP instance is sitting behind a WebSocket.

So if your app is working as expected (maybe just takes a bit too long to get connected) & has this error in development console it's likely due to a proxy server. To avoid this try getting SSL (https://) installed on your server too. This way the ISP or proxy is not able to alter your app's connection.

Comment: I will look into step 3. Thank you Akshat. Would you happen to know if it is necessary to use aws load balancer in order to use ssl on the instance? I have set up the load balancer with my certificate and now installing nginx and attempting to configure the .congif file for my app

Comment: @meteorBuzz Yes, this is the reason. The AWS Load balancer does not support websockets. I wish you mentioned that. You may have to consider disabling websockets (environment variable `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=t`) or use something else to load balancer, like nginx.

Comment: I have removed the balancer, and going going to install nginx on the instance and install my comodo certificate following https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx

Comment: If you change the ELB to load balance on layer 4 (TCP) then websockets will work, but any websocket emulation based on HTTP polling may fail. Your best bet is to use HAProxy with IP or HTTP path hashing depending on the incoming protocol. FWIW, Nginx also supports IP hashing in its paid version, but it's pretty pricey.

Comment: @aembke on ELB TCP load balancing you can't use SSL easily.

Comment: You'll probably have to create a second listener on 443 for tcp ssl. We have one of our servers deployed that way and it seems to work. Although it still won't solve your problem if you use sockjs or socketio and use the fallback http polling.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was connecting via a hotel WiFi. The problem was that you are always connecting to the internet via their proxy.

My solution to this was to use my mobile phone as a Wifi hotspot. I have Android 6.0.1, and you can access the menu through:

`Settings > More > Tethering & portable hotspot > Set up Wi-Fi hotspot (and then enable 'Portable Wi-Fi hotspot')`