# WebSocket handshake responds 400, but still works

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I use `socket.io` to make a chat room in my website, there is no problem when I run it in my computer, but when I run it on the production server, the `socket.io.js` output the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://myWebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=1qtzy4QRde6G-PHkAAAU' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I am using `socket.io@1.4.5` for server and client

The website is listening on port `8080` behind `nginx` with port `80`, everything works fine except the error message, but the chat room is still functional, that is very strange.

I have searched some similar issues on Stack Overflow, and the suggested solutions are already my `nginx` settings (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myWebsite.com`):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myWebsite.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        }
}
```

[Meteor WebSocket handshake error 400 with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014969/meteor-websocket-handshake-error-400-with-nginx)
[Meteor WebSocket connection to 'ws://.../websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171179/meteor-websocket-connection-to-ws-websocket-failed-error-during-websock)

Although the chat room still works, I still want to get rid of the error message

For your reference, below is the `socket.io` related code:

```
// I use angular.js as the front-end framework
function Socket (socketFactory, $rootScope) {
    var ioSocket = io.connect(window.location.host);
    var socket = socketFactory({ioSocket : ioSocket});
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
Socket.$inject = ['socketFactory', '$rootScope'];
angular.module('core').factory('Socket', Socket);

Socket.on('new message', function (data) { ... });
```

Comment: So how does the socket connect? Is it sending second request? Is it even upgrading to websockets or it backups to xhr?

Comment: I don't really know how that works, I just opened two browser tabs, both of them had the 400 response, but both could receive messages from each other

Answer (score -1):

Just realized that my website is using CloudFlare, the problem is solved since I had disabled the proxy.